# Как установить модули npm на Ubuntu 14.04 LTS?

Tags: ubuntu, angularjs, npm, node.js

Сервак запускается, но в браузере пишет просто *Loading...* и все.
В консоль валятся ошибки *404*
При запуске `gulp default`:

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir '/mnt/PROJECTS/[3]_PROCOM/[8]_POKAZATOR/WIP/front/node_modules/node-sass/vendor'
at Object.fs.readdirSync (fs.js:870:18)
at Object.getInstalledBinaries (/mnt/PROJECTS/[3]_PROCOM/[8]_POKAZATOR/WIP/front/node_modules/node-sass/lib/extensions.js:121:13)
at foundBinariesList (/mnt/PROJECTS/[3]_PROCOM/[8]_POKAZATOR/WIP/front/node_modules/node-sass/lib/errors.js:20:15)
at foundBinaries (/mnt/PROJECTS/[3]_PROCOM/[8]_POKAZATOR/WIP/front/node_modules/node-sass/lib/errors.js:15:5)
at Object.module.exports.missingBinary (/mnt/PROJECTS/[3]_PROCOM/[8]_POKAZATOR/WIP/front/node_modules/node-sass/lib/errors.js:45:5)
at module.exports (/mnt/PROJECTS/[3]_PROCOM/[8]_POKAZATOR/WIP/front/node_modules/node-sass/lib/binding.js:15:30)
at Object.<anonymous> (/mnt/PROJECTS/[3]_PROCOM/[8]_POKAZATOR/WIP/front/node_modules/node-sass/lib/index.js:14:35)
at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
```

Короче, не ставится *node-sass*
При попытке установить через `sudo npm install node-sass`:

```
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/mnt/PROJECTS/[3]_PROCOM/[8]_POKAZATOR/WIP/front/node_modules/node-sass/build'
gyp ERR! System Linux 3.13.0-106-generic
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/mnt/PROJECTS/[3]_PROCOM/[8]_POKAZATOR/WIP/front/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
gyp ERR! cwd /mnt/PROJECTS/[3]_PROCOM/[8]_POKAZATOR/WIP/front/node_modules/node-sass

gyp ERR! node -v v7.2.1

gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.4.0

gyp ERR! not ok 

Build failed with error code: 1

npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-106-generic

npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "node-sass"

npm ERR! node v7.2.1

npm ERR! npm  v2.15.11

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! node-sass@4.1.1 postinstall: `node scripts/build.js`

npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 

npm ERR! Failed at the node-sass@4.1.1 postinstall script 'node scripts/build.js'.

npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the node-sass package,

npm ERR! not with npm itself.

npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:

npm ERR!     node scripts/build.js

npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project 
with:

npm ERR!     npm bugs node-sass

npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:

npm ERR! 

npm ERR!     npm owner ls node-sass

npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.


npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:

npm ERR!     /mnt/PROJECTS/[3]_PROCOM/[8]_POKAZATOR/WIP/front/npm-debug.log
```

Говорит что ему, типа, не хватает прав админа, хотя ставится он от sudo и права папке даны через `sudo chmod 777 -R ...`

С проектом *phone-cat* такая же проблема, тока там компоненты *bower* не ставятся.

```
Linux Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
npm v2.15.11
nodejs v7.2.1
```

Вопросы:

1. Как каким-либо другим способом (не через терминал) поставить *node-sass*?
2. Как поставить компоненты *bower*?
3. Почему возникают такие проблемы?

Comment: как вы устанавливали nodejs? в какой директории вы запускаете `npm install`?

Comment: https://github.com/sass/node-sass

Comment: Some users have reported issues installing on Ubuntu due to node being registered to another package. Follow the official NodeJS docs to install NodeJS so that #!/usr/bin/env node correctly resolved.

Comment: npm install в корне запускала, там где packages.json

Comment: Как устанавливали nodejs уже не помню, поразному, потом еще обновляла...

Comment: у вас проект лежит в корне? удалите все и попробуйте nvm.

Comment: всмысле удалить все?) форматнуть винт?)))

Comment: Вот это решение: https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions  не помогло

Comment: думаю, что удалить nodejs будет достаточно. так где у вас проект лежит?

Comment: Ну сам проект лежит в папке проекты на соседнем от рута жестком диске. nodejs можно удалить, вопрос в том, как его корректно поставить?

Comment: это у вас случайно не виртуальная машина? а диск случайно не сетевой?

Comment: Нет, у меня не виртуальная машина, и диск не сетевой.

Comment: просто вот такой путь `/mnt/PROJECTS/[3]_PROCOM/[8]_POKAZATOR/WIP/front/node_modules/node-sass` выглядит очень странно для unix-подобной системы